# How can I make React Router work in the bundle.js file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Everything is just fine when I'm developing via local server, but when I turn the code into bundle.js with webpack, I get the following message:

bundle.js:22468 Warning: [react-router] Location "/some directory..." did not match any routes

There are similar questions, but none of them is webpack related. My code so far looks like that:

```
export default (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path='/signup' component={signup} />
    <Route path='/signin' component={signin} />
    </Route>
)
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Is `/some directory` a route? It's not listed in your routes...

Comment: that's just an example... I didn't want to write the directory there.

Comment: "bundled" code should behave the same way in local development and production. you haven't provided enough information to answer this question. How are you loading the bundle? is the bundled code running on a server? what is the relevant route?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Sorry, I'm beginner. I load with the command "webpack". No server, I want to run it though the index.html file. relevant route? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: just curious, but in your webpack config file, do you have output with a `publicPath: '/'` setting?

Comment: Yes, I do. output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },